# Larger tkinter table out of Entrys becoming very slow

Tags: python, excel, tkinter, scrollbar

I want to display data in a kind of table, scroll-able in y and resizing in x direction.
For showing text in a single cell i use the entry widget.
I want to separate the cells in x and y direction by a thin line
and i want a additionally frame in the cells what i can dye

It should look something like in my code below.
The problem is, with more data, the window becomes extremely slow
(window moving, windows resizing) the scrolling function is very unsmooth
(with mouse wheel a little better as moving the scrollbar)

Is there a way, to make this more smooth or is Python / tkinter just the wrong tool for this?
Why can Excel handle big tables so easy?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=frame, tags=("inner_frame",))

frame.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), minsize=40)

innerborders = []
c = 0
for i in range(150):
    for j in range(10):

        innerborders.append(tk.Frame(frame, bg="white"))
        innerborders[c].grid(column=j, row=i, sticky="nesw", padx=(0, 1), pady=(0, 1))

        entry = tk.Entry(innerborders[c],width=1, disabledbackground="white", disabledforeground="black", borderwidth=0)
        entry.insert(0, "Entry")
        entry["state"]="disabled"
        entry.pack(padx=2, pady=2, fill="both")

        c+=1

innerborders[11]["bg"] = "red"
innerborders[32]["bg"] = "green"
innerborders[34]["bg"] = "yellow"
innerborders[41]["bg"] = "blue"

def canvas_resize(event):
    border = int(canvas.cget("borderwidth"))
    event.widget.itemconfigure("inner_frame", width=event.width-border*2)

def frame_resize(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def _on_mousewheel(event):
    if not scrollbar.get()[0] == 0.0 or not scrollbar.get()[1] == 1.0:
        canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 60)), "units")

canvas.bind("<Configure>", canvas_resize)
frame.bind("<Configure>", frame_resize)
frame.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

root.mainloop()
```